# MySQL - Filter records using SUM

Tags: mysql

I've a student table like below -

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`student` (
  `student_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `student_marks` INT NULL);
```

I want to find the student whose **sum of marks** is greater than 500, but I am not able to filter the records, however I develop below query.

```
mysql> select * from student;
+------------+---------------+
| student_id | student_marks |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |           220 |
|          2 |           100 |
|          3 |           280 |
|          2 |           430 |
|          1 |           300 |
+------------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select student_id, sum(student_marks) from student group by student_id;
+------------+--------------------+
| student_id | sum(student_marks) |
+------------+--------------------+
|          1 |                520 |
|          2 |                530 |
|          3 |                280 |
+------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HAVING clause: `select student_id, sum(student_marks) from student group by student_id having sum(student_marks) > 500;`

Comment: How to make the sum of marks in DESC?

Comment: `select student_id, sum(student_marks) from student 
group by student_id having sum(student_marks) > 500 order by sum(student_marks) desc;`

Answer (score 0):

We can do like below -

```
mysql> select * from ( select student_id, sum(student_marks) as marks_of_student from student group by student_id) as f  where f.marks_of_student > 500;
+------------+------------------+
| student_id | marks_of_student |
+------------+------------------+
|          1 |              520 |
|          2 |              530 |
+------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```